# This is with regards to usage of Present Perfect or present tense

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

Question is :

He____(be) carrying his wallet for three years. He thinks it _____(be) lucky for him.

What should (be) be replaced with and why?

It seems the answer is

He **has been**(be) carrying his wallet for three years. He thinks it **is** (be) lucky 
for him.

My question now is why it is

He thinks it **is** lucky for him

and not

He thinks it **has been** lucky for him.

Answer (score 1):

> **He has been carrying the wallet for three years**.
>
> **He thinks it is lucky for him**.
>
> **He  thinks it has been lucky for him**

Though both   *it is lucky for him*  and   *it has been lucky for him* seem to be  correct, since it is his belief which is permanant in nature the author might have preferred **it is lucky for him**. we consider something causes luck or unluck.So the simple present is the preferred  form since it talks about a belief.

Answer (score 0):

> "He has been carrying his wallet for three years."

We can understand that he is still carrying his wallet. Present perfect is used to talk about time up to now.

> "He thinks it is lucky for him."

Simple present tense is used to say that it happens regularly. Because his wallet is always lucky for him.